# Vuetify Autocompletes not Working Properly with IOS Voice Over

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, accessibility, vuetify.js

I am trying to make an autocomplete that follows the W3 accessibility standards for screen readers: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/examples/combobox/combobox-autocomplete-list.html

The workflow should be the user types something into the box and swipes right on the screen to enter the dropdown and make a selection, however, on IOS specifically, the dropdown is rendered at the end of the DOM and users have to swipe all the way to the end where they are jumped backed up to the autocomplete dropdown. This has been true for all vuetify examples of selects and autocompletes, even the one on the accessibility page.

Does anyone have a work around for this?